# Add Tab on click with component content with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a tab dynamically when user clicks on a link. Tab should be selected and the content is a component. If another link is clicked a tab with different component should be added.

```
<button mat-raised-button  (click)="addTab('Content 1', '\<app-content1>\</app-content1>')">
  Add content1
</button>

<mat-tab-group #tabgroup>
  <mat-tab #blankTab>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab.caption">
    {{ tab.content }}
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


export class TesttabsComponent implements OnInit {

  tabs = [{ caption: 'First', content: '<p>first</p>' }, { caption: 'Second', content: '<p>second</p>' }];


  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addTab(caption: string, content: string) {
    this.tabs.push({ caption: caption, content: content });
  }
}
```

The Problem is when clicking it will output  instead of evaluation the component

Comment: Perhaps its not clear enough
I have a menu with some links. Each link should create a tab (angular material) with its specific component.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and why it hasn't worked, or at least the research you've done and where you're stuck. Otherwise, it feels like you're using SO as a free architecture service, and I'm not sure many people will be willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem is to use *ngComponentOutlet

```
<mat-tab-group #tabgroup>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index" [label]="tab.caption">    
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.content"></ng-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


tabs = [{ caption: 'First', content: Content1Component }, { caption: 'Second', content: Content2Component }];
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addTab(caption: string, content: string) {
    this.tabs.push({ caption: caption, content: Content1Component });
  }
```